Why is my dunder variable defined at module scope not recognized from a function scope as int but recognized as list[int]?
I tried to make a variable as "private" in the module using __dunder_case__ and use it in the function below.
I finally changed the variable name to uppercase naming and forget about anything private when using python.
I'm running python 3.12.2 on windows 11.
But I cannot wrap my mind around why is it treated this way...
__use_this__ = 0


def test_out_scope():
    __use_this__ += 1
    return __use_this__


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__use_this__)
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())

and expecting to add the variable but got this instead:
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable '__use_this__' where it is not associated with a value.

Edited
__use_this__ = [0]



def test_out_scope():
    __use_this__[0] += 1
    return __use_this__[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__use_this__[0])
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())
    print(test_out_scope())

expecting to fail

The underscores have NOTHING to do with what you're seeing.  Double underscores at both ends do not have any effect on privacy, anyway.  The issue is that in the first version, test_out_scope() contains an assignment to the variable, which makes it a local variable by default - completely unrelated to the global with the same name.  The second version doesn't actually assign to the variable, so it is still a global.

How about you actually mention the actual problem you're encountering? You haven't mentioned any indication of an error, or what exactly "goes wrong" in any way.

Python doesn't have private variables. Double underscore name mangling doesn't make anything private, and it only applies to variables in class definition statements

This has nothing to do with variable naming. Double underscore only makes variable names behave differently in class definitions - it is treated like any other variable otherwise.
The reason you're seeing an error when __use_this__ == 0 is simply because of incorrect reference to nonlocal variable. Because integers are immutable - += doesn't work in place with immutable variables. It creates a new object (well, not really but for simplicity let's say it does) and assigns it to the variable name. Since you are reassigning name inside a function, it is treated as local and throws UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable '__use_this__' where it is not associated with a value.
When you are modifying a list, it still points to the same list object. Since you don't assign it anywhere in the function, it looks for the reference in outer scope.
Simply marking a variable as global will solve the issue.
def test_out_scope():
    global __use_this__
    __use_this__ += 1
    return __use_this__


It doesn't matter if += operates in place for this issue. If they'd done __use_this__ += [1] with the list, it'd mutate the list instead of creating a new object, but they'd still get an UnboundLocalError.
